# How do I pass username and password from Python code to PowerShell?

Tags: python, powershell

I have a PowerShell script, which I will be running from a Python script.

Here is the script to run PowerShell from Python:

```
subprocess.call("C:\\code\\Desktop\\test.ps1")
```

After executing the above command from Python, it prompts for username and password.

Username:

Password:

some extra information

Now, Here is my question. How do I pass user name and password from Python script?

Comment: i think it's dangerous.

Comment: You could pass username and password as commandline arguments or as environment variables, but that may require changes to the PowerShell script.

Comment: As @AnsgarWiechers suggests, you need access to the PowerShell script or you need to check its params. It ought to have parameters set up, like `test.ps1 -Username Value -Password OtherValue`, etc., but you need to see the file's insides to know.